# Reboot device programmatically does'nt work while adb does

Tags: android, root

In my application there's a function to reboot which works fine with any rooted device... until now.

My newest test device (Android 4.2) doesn't react in any way. But using the adb prompt with the same command does the trick.

First I determine if the device is rooted which returns true:

```
String[] places = {"/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/", "/data/local/xbin/", "/data/local/bin/", "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/"};
for (String where : places) {
    if (new File(where + "su").exists()) {
        isDeviceRootedResult = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

After that i try to execute the command like this:

```
Process rebootProcess = null;
rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c reboot now");
if (rebootProcess != null) rebootProcess.waitFor();
```

I don't see any output in my LogCat, no exceptions, no throw, nothing...

While the "same" adb command works fine:

```
adb.exe shell "su -c reboot now"
```

Comment: You must have your devide rooted...

Comment: My function above returns true. Is the way I determine root access wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reboot your device programmatically if your device is not rooted! It;s a question of security. You probably don't have superuser rights

Comment: My function above returns true. Is the way I determine root access wrong?

Comment: I don;t know what "return true" means regarding your function. The idea of Android is that you cannot affect external apps or processes within your app. This is how Android works. It's a security feature. In order to do that you must root your device!